# rails application redirecting without the prefix

Tags: url

I have a problem with my web app..the urls all work fine with the exception of the following case.

When I try to access my app without the www prefix

http://myapp.com/mypath

the url changes to www.myapp.commypath - no slash between domain name and the path

every other combination of the url works just fine, but this one, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can say something about your setup: what is doing the redirecting, for example. I expect that is actually being done by apache or nginx, and I would first have a look at their config.

Comment: Sorry Niels, I should have been more specific and in retrospect it's not a rails problem as it's not even hitting my app..the url in the browser is just changing from http://myapp.com/new to www.myapp.comnew